# What is this CompositionContainer code in my c# windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am looking at an existing c# windows service project and I have this function that's called in it's constructor ie. before the win service OnStart event. Please can someone please explain what this does? What if I remove this from my service?

```
    private void Compose()
    {
        CompositionContainer container = null;

        try
        {
            string codebase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(codebase);
            container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException ex)
        {
            foreach (var error in ex.Errors)
            {
                _logger.Fatal("Error when loading plugin", error.Exception);
            }
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {
            foreach (var error in ex.LoaderExceptions)
            {
                _logger.Fatal("Error when searching for plugin", error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Fatal("Error when loading plugin", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (container != null)
            {
                container.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps MSDN can help you with that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its MEF right there (allows you to load plugins on demand). More detailed info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing for sure what is in the `catalog`, my guess is that this code should not be removed.  The [`CompositionContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is part of the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft for creating and managing extensible applications, i.e., plug-ins, which would be defined by `catalog`.  Without this code, I would presume the service would cease to do its defined function.